# Insert dynamic textfield cells into section in TableView - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I am a beginner in Swift and i am stuck with a problem.

I have a TableView Controller which contains 3 sections, the first two are composed of one textfield in one cell. 
However, for the third one at the beginning, it has only one cell (textfield). 
Each time the user presses Return on the textfield, i would like to insert one row composed of one textfield below the textfield edited. (Like when you add multiple phone numbers in the Contacts App).

I created a UITextField Array : TextFieldArrayPayers

My code looks like this : 
Connected to the textField when user presses Return :

```
@IBAction func AddParticipant(sender: AnyObject) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        textFieldArrayPayers.append(UITextField());
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
            NSIndexPath(forRow: textFieldArrayPayers.count, inSection: 2)
            ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

    }
```

And to manage my sections :

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section==2
    {
        return textFieldArrayPayers.count+1
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

When I run my program, i try to edit the first textfield and when I press Enter or Return, I get this :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException',
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

I looked at numerous similar topics but never found the real solution..

Thanks in advance for those who got the solution

Comment: What is the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Empty, I do not know how to implement it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your model before beginning your batch update:

```
@IBAction func AddParticipant(sender: AnyObject) {

        textFieldArrayPayers.append(UITextField());

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
            NSIndexPath(forRow: textFieldArrayPayers.count, inSection: 2)
            ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

    }
```

For more information on see the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9)

Comment: With this : @IBAction func AddParticipant(sender: AnyObject) {
  let index = NSIndexPath(forRow: textFieldArrayPayers.count, inSection: 2)
  myTableView.beginUpdates();
  myTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([index], withRowAnimation: .Automatic);
  myTableView.endUpdates();
  
 }

Comment: What are you saying? The code you provided fixed your problem? Or that's your interpretation of the code I provided?

Comment: Sorry ;) I tried with this and still the same problem.. I think it comes from the implementation of cellRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I agree. Make sure you're not trying to use a static table view.

Comment: I manage to add dynamic rows (static cells mode before....). Now, I have a textfield on each cell, i wonder how to get the text of each one once the user presses the top right button. I guess i have to use the indexPath with each section, but i don't know how to do when i have multiple dynamic rows (maybe in cellRowAtIndexPath) ?